# Alternative proof that $f(x) = $ sin $\frac{1}{x^x}$ is not uniformly continuous on (0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

My idea is to make use of this theorem:

"A real-valued funtion $f$ on $(a,b)$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ if and only if it can be extended to a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$."

My reasoning is that since sin $\frac{1}{x^x}$ oscillates infinitely near the origin, it cannot be made continuous by extending $f$ by assigning any value to $f(x)$ for the case when $x = 0$.

Is this a valid line of reasoning? How could I make it mathematically precise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not work, since$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\sin\left(\frac1{x^x}\right)=\sin\left(\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{x^x}\right)=\sin(1).$$Actually, it follows from this that your function *is* continuous on $(0,1]$, since you can extend it to a continuous function from $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb R$.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, this is because $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 1$. This follows from rewriting $x^x = e^{x \log x}$ and the fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} x \log x = 0$, which can be proved by rewriting $x \log x = \frac{\log x}{1 / x}$ and applying L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @jose I apologize - I meant sin $\frac{1}{x^2}$. It is my mistake. But I am glad for your answer regarding $\frac{1}{x^x}$. It is interesting to think about.  Does this change the answer to my question?

Comment: Totally. If it is $\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$ instead of $\sin\left(\frac1{x^x}\right)$ then indeed the limit at $0$ does not exist, and therefore the function is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Another thing: do you have no problem, after having got an answer to your question, to edit it into a different question, to which the answer does not apply?

Comment: @jose You are right. I reverted my question to as I posted so others will not be confused in the future. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.